# activity_registo_login.xml:19: error: '43' is incompatible with attribute layout_height (attr) dimension|enum

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to make an Android application, but I am receiving a compile error.
And I cannot find what's wrong with the code.

```
package com.example.gonca.smartstudy;

public class RegistoLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText nome;
    private EditText Password;
    private TextView info;
    private Button Login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registo_login);

        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    }

    private void valdiar(String NomeUtilizador, String PasswordUtilizador) {

        if ((NomeUtilizador == "Admistrador") && (PasswordUtilizador == "1234")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistoLogin.this, segunda_actividade.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to look into the xml file the error message states. You will find the line with the problem underlined.

Comment: i have loocked and the only thing that I can find is Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\gonca\AndroidStudioProjects\SmartStudy\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_registo_login.xml:19: error: '43' is incompatible with attribute layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
error: failed linking file resources

Comment: Hit Ctrl+Shift+N, enter activity_registo_login.xml and hit return. Go to line 43 and change it to wrap_content.